# WiX ComponentGroup Condition

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, conditional-statements, wix3.10

I have a `Feature`, which references a `ComponentGroup`.  That `ComponentGroup` is defined in a `Fragment` in another file and contains number of `Component`s.

This project is shared across multiple versions of the product and I would like to maintain one version of the Product.wxs file (the codebase is common between the product versions).

Can I set a Condition on a ComponentGroup to determine whether or not to include it in the installer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. The code snippet below is perfectly valid WiX code:

```
<Feature Id="MyFeature" Title="Some title" Level="100">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroup1"/>
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroup2"/>
  <?if $(var.IncludeAnotherGroup) = true ?>
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="AnotherGroup"/>
  <?endif ?>
</Feature>
```

You can supply the value of `IncludeAnotherGroup` variable at build time, e.g. like this (NAnt code):

```
<candle ...>
  <defines>
    <define name="IncludeAnotherGroup" value="true" />
  </defines>
  <sources basedir="${paths.wxs}">
    <include name="**.wxs"/>
  </sources>
</candle>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed.  I am calling the build from command line using the visual studio solution.  I am modifying the value of the version string in my config.wxi prior to building the installer (prior to building the entire codebase, to be exact).  Can wix variables be set from msbuild command line?

Comment: @Jon, There's a bunch of official docs about using MSBuild with WiX: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/

Comment: This may work for the original asker, but I note this doesn't answer the actual question of whether you can use a [Condition](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/condition.html) element inside a [ComponentGroup](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/componentgroup.html) element. The answer appears to be No.